# Compile scripts using dataweave library in Java

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to compile script using dataweave runtime library. Below is the sample code:

DataWeaveScript dataWeaveScript= weaveScriptingEngine.compile(script, NameIdentifier nameIdentifier, InputType[] implicitInputs, "application/json");

Can anyone help suggesting what should be passed in Name Identifier and InputType[].

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add more explanation? Do you have any document reference of `weaveScriptingEngine.compile` or `DataWeaveScript`?. Version of mule runtime that you are using. And what is `dataweave runtime library`?

Comment: I am using this dataweave  runtime library- <groupId>org.mule.weave</groupId>
    <artifactId>runtime</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>   Sorry I don't have any reference docs, I am trying to use compile method declared in this class DataWeaveScriptingEngine.scala .DataWeaveScriptingEngine is available from above shared runtime library

Comment: You are trying to rely on internal components. DataWeave is not meant to be used in this way today. If this is something you need inside Mule, I suggest taking a look at their `ExpressionLanguage` API, which delegates to DataWeave.

Comment: https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/data-weave-cli/blob/master/native-cli/src/main/scala/org/mule/weave/dwnative/NativeRuntime.scala . Please help provide more insights into Dataweave API usages here @HarshankBansal